# MySQL creating custom date range for daily reports

Tags: mysql, sql

MySql 8.0

I have dataset that looks something like this:

```
user_id        transaction_time      item_price
   1          2020-01-01 13:00:00       100 
   1          2020-01-01 18:00:00       100 
   1          2020-01-01 19:00:00       100 
   1          2020-01-01 23:00:00       100 
   1          2020-01-02 04:00:00       100 
   1          2020-01-02 09:00:00       100
```

Usually if I want to find sum(price) for daily price I would do

```
select date(transcation_time) as dt
     , sum(item_price) as sum_price
from table
group by date(transaction_time)
```

which would output

```
   dt       sum_price
2020-01-01     400
2020-01-02     200
```

But instead of `2020-01-01` summing price from `2020-01-01 00:00:00` to `2020-01-01 23:59:59` I want to sum prices from `2020-01-01 18:00:00` to `2020-01-02 06:00:00` which would be marked as `2020-01-01`

so

```
2020-01-01   sums prices from 2020-01-01 18:00:00 ~ 2020-01-02 06:00:00 
2020-01-02   sums prices from 2020-01-02 18:00:00 ~ 2020-01-03 06:00:00 
2020-01-03   sums prices from 2020-01-03 18:00:00 ~ 2020-01-04 06:00:00
```

and so on...

then my resulting aggregation would look like this:

```
   dt       sum_price
2020-01-01     500
2020-01-02     100
```

note that first row isn't added since 13:00:00 is not in 18:00:00 ~06:00:00

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm assuming this is because the `transaction_time` value is in UTC but you want it grouped by date adjusted for your local timezone?

Comment: If you do want it adjusted for your timezone, **don't do a trivial `DATEADD`** - this is because a timezone's UTC offset varies based on daylight savings. What is the real data-type of the `transaction_time` column?

Comment: @Dai Not trying to change timezones, I want subset of hours in 24 hours range. notice that 18~06(next day) != 24 hours

Comment: Why would you want only 12 hours for the sum?

Comment: @GordonLinoff because I other prices within other times are noises to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to subtract 6 hours -- or add 18 hours:

```
select date(transaction_time + interval -6 hour) as dt,
       sum(item_price) as sum_price
from table
group by dt;
```

If you really do only want 12 hours, then add a `where` clause:

```
select date(transaction_time + interval -6 hour) as dt,
       sum(item_price) as sum_price
from table
where time(transaction_time) >= '18:00:00' or
      time(transaction_time) < '06:00:00' 
group by dt
```

Comment: The OP is using MySQL which supports referencing `SELECT` expressions in the `GROUP BY`, but that's not ISO SQL compliant. All other systems require the expression to be repeated in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Dai . . . Not all databases.  In fact, a majority nowadays probably do allow aliases in the `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to include 06:00:00 ~ 18:00:00 date as well which I don't want.

Comment: @Ambleu . . . I actually figured that was a typo in the question.  A `where` clause is all you need.